# Composer: The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to use `composer.json` file. but, when I am trying to run command '`composer install`' in my `path/project/`, I am getting an error:

[image]

I have already configured my `wamp` for '`extension=php_intl.dll`' and copied all `icu*.dll` in '`D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin`' from '`D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13`' and it's showing in `phpinfo()`:

[image]

without copy `icu*.dll` also works and showing in `phpinfo()`;

Kindly, let me know if I have **`intl`** install on my **`wamp`** and **`composer install`** on my pc then why I am getting this error. really, it is so annoying.

Here is my details:

1. OS: windows 7 (64)
2. PHP: 5.3.13
3. Apache:2.2.22
4. Composer: installed by executable file
5. Pear: installed (latest)
6. PHPUnit: installed (latest)

My **`composer.json`** is as below:

```
{
    "name" : "sebastian/money",
    "description" : "Value Object that represents a monetary value (using a currency's smallest unit)",
    "keywords" : ["money"],
    "homepage" : "http://www.github.com/sebastianbergmann/money",
    "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
    "authors" : [{
            "name" : "Sebastian Bergmann",
            "email" : "sebastian@phpunit.de"
        }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3.3",
        "ext-intl" : "*"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "classmap" : [
            "src/"
        ]
    },
    "extra" : {
        "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "1.3.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any other details is required..

Any feedback/help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

PHP uses a different php.ini for command line php than for the web/apache php. So you see the intl extension in phpinfo() in the browser, but if you run `php -m` in the command line you might see that the list of extensions there does not include intl.

You can check using `php -i` on top of the output it should tell you where the ini file is loaded from. Make sure you enable the intl extension in that ini file and you should be good to go.

For php.ini 5.6 version (check version using php -v)

```
;extension=php_intl.dll 
; remove semicolon
extension=php_intl.dll
```

For php.ini 7.* version

```
;extension=intl
; remove semicolon
extension=intl
```

Comment: Thank you so much Seldaek, You are right, There is different PHP.ini for CLI. Its 'D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini' and for WEB its 'D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini'. So, I had to edit CLI php.ini too. Now its working. if anybody want to know what php.ini CLI using then just run php -i on CMD or better way $ php -i > php.txt. it will save output in php.txt file then you can know php.ini path by 'Loaded Configuration File => '. Ciya!! and once again Thanks allot!!

Comment: `php --ini` will show CLI configuration file names.

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu-like systems we can install `mbstring` extension using the command: `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

Comment: In my case on Ubuntu 16.04 running a LAMP stack: **Un-comment** (i.e. remove the suffix ; symbol) `extension=php_intl.dll` in the php.ini of **web/apache php** && **Leave** the php.ini of **php-cli** as it was _(because doing the same for php-cli made php through this error in terminal: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library... )_ || And all worked well after this!

Comment: My paths states: Loaded Configuration File => (none) 
How dod I find the php.ini file now? Why does it say none... :(

Comment: It gives me system error ( MSVCP140.dll is missing from your computer). I have XAMPP v3.2.4 on Windows.

Comment: I don't save as a php.ini file . get system error " You Don't have permission to open this file "

Comment: Removing semicolon before  extension=intl line in php.ini file worked for me.

Comment: Great. Thank you so  much. My PHP 7.x  ;extension=intl

Comment: `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`
This will show the loaded config file path

Answer (score 163):

I encountered this using it in Mac, resolved it by using `--ignore-platform-reqs` option.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

After installing with this method, if the package that defines the requirement attempts to use any functions from the specified PHP extension, it will fail irrevocably.

Comment: Actually worked for me better than the other solutions. May have to add that --ignore-platform-reqs is a composer option for the ones who like to try it also :)

Comment: Done it on Lubuntu - there's nothing more legit than this

Comment: Can someone give some input about any drawback related to the use of this flag?

Comment: @S.Dre as Healyhatman explained 2 answers below, this ignores apparently ignores the problem, I've found this [old ressource](https://hannesvdvreken.com/2015/01/18/composer-ignore-platform-reqs-flag/), it states that this flag disables some kind of check between the PHP system installed and what extensions are available, hence could somewhat ignore the problem, but it is nuanced, there are some uses cases for this flag where it is useful, the blog post states those use cases.

Comment: I figured so @AkechiShiro, any flag with *ignore* should be treated with a grain of salt.

Comment: @S.Dre the package defined this requirement because it uses the extension somewhere. If you ignore the requirement, your web page will die as soon as it hits the line where the extension is used. This is bad advice.

Comment: Yes @miken32. A red flag rose in my head as soon as I saw that flag (no pun intended). That's why I asked. Something told me this was kind of wrong.

Answer (score 46):

In linux (Debian Jessie for example):

```
apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

will make the job to you due will create a simbolic link to it.

Comment: thanks, make sure the module is installed first, then do what this answer says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345369/4628115

Comment: Should be noted that the version of PHP that you want to install this for should be adjusted. Example if you wanted to install it for PHP 7.3 you'd do: 

sudo apt-get install php7.3-intl

Answer (score 18):

To enable intl extension follow the instructions below.

You need enable extension by uncommenting the following line extension=php_intl.dll in the C:\xampp\php\php.ini file.
 Once you uncomment the extension=php_intl.dll, then you must restart apache server using XAMPP control panel.

```
//about line 998
;extension=php_intl.dll 
change as
extension=php_intl.dll
```

(Note: php.ini file mostly in the following directory C:\xampp\php)

Restart xampp

Answer (score 3):

If You have got this error while running composer install command,
don't worry.
Steps to be followed and requirements:

- Step1: Go to server folder such as xampp(or) wampp etc.
- Step2: open php folder inside that and go to ext folder.
- Step3: If you find a file named as **php_intl.dll** no problem.

Just go to php.ini file and uncomment the line

From:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

To:

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

- Step4: restart xampp, thats it

**Note:** If you don't find any of the file named as
**php_intl.dll**, then you need to upgrade the PHP version.

Comment: I have XAMPP v3.2.4 on Windows. I have php_intl.dll in 'ext folder'. but, In php.ini file, there is ';extension=intl' line, I have uncommented it & follow your instruction. It gives me system error ( MSVCP140.dll is missing from your computer).

Answer (score 3):

just remove them

```
"ext-intl" : "*"
```

from your composer.json file.

Because sometimes for some helper functions, the IDE complains that the extension is missing from the composer.json file. Immediately press Alt+Enter to add it to the composer. But that doesn't mean that composer will count them in. The composer will complain next time while doing some operations. So that, we should not blindly type Alt+Enter rather than installing them manually in composer by doing `composer install <package-name>`.

As I think you have entered it manually, you should remove it, then install it in proper procedure `composer install <package-name>`

Or else you can run `composer update` to count that added dependencies in.

Answer (score 2):

(with xampp server)open php.ini in "*.\xampp\php*"

change ***;extension=intl*** to ***extension=intl***

Answer (score 1):

This is bit old question but I had faced same problem on linux base server while installing magento 2.

When I am firing `composer update` or `composer install` command from my magento root dir. Its was firing below error.

```
Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
  Problem 2
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mbstring * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for pelago/emogrifier 0.1.1 -> satisfiable by pelago/emogrifier[v0.1.1].
    - pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
   ...
```

Then, I searched for the available intl & intl extensions, using below commands.

```
yum list php*intl
yum install php-intl.x86_64  

yum list php*mbstring
yum install php-mbstring.x86_64
```

And it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In latest XAMPP version;
You need to find only intl(Line no 912)in php.ini file.
Change
;extension=intl
To
extension=intl

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using ubuntu, run this command, it will be solved if your system is also ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on my server. And it is mainly happened due to miss-match of php version between server version and your system version. I am using Nginx and checked on all my project configuration files, it uses php8.0 but on my terminal it shows php.8.1. Actually my application needs php8.0. The following steps resolved my issue.

To see all my running php versions

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

It shows the following page
[image: php all versions page]

Selecting php8.0 for my application. Run the command to see Nginx scripts are ok

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Then reload the Nginx

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Finally go to your project directory and update or install your composer

```
composer update
```

It has been resolved my issue, I expect same will resolve yours.