# Cannot Install Laravel Package - Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-4, package

So I am following the tutorial on tuts+ Premium from Jeffrey Way - Creating an Ecommerce App in Laravel 4 and I am stuck with this problem. He is installing a package by just editing the composer.json file with this line `"intervention/image": "dev-master"` and then just types 'composer update' into his console. I try the same but it won't work.

It displays this error

"
  Problem 1
    - intervention/image 2.0.2 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for intervention/image 2.* -> satisfiable by interven
tion/image[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2]."

I have tried following their instructions on http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation but it wouldn't work.

I don't know how to handle this issue. Please help. I also read somewhere that I should edit the php.ini file and uncomment a line for fileinfo but after restarting Apache again it did not work.

I am using Windows 8 with wamp and Laravel.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure that, you have `php_fileinfo.dll` is installed/available in your `php\ext` folder and also make sure that, the following line is not commented in `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

If it's commented like this:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Then just remove that `;` from the beginning of the line and then restart the `wamp/apache` server.

**Update:**

> However, some web servers are confusing because they do not use the
>   php.ini located alongside your PHP executable. To find out where your
>   actual php.ini resides, look for its path in phpinfo():

After activating an extension, save php.ini, restart the web server and check phpinfo() again. The new extension should now have its own section.

Also check the `Installing a PHP extension on Windows` ([Resolving problems](http://www.php.net//manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.problemsolving)) on `PHP` manual.

Comment: php_fileinfo.dll is in my php/ext folder in wamp and also that line is uncommented as I said before: " I also read somewhere that I should edit the php.ini file and uncomment a line for fileinfo but after restarting Apache again it did not work."
Thanks for being willing to help. I appreciate it.

Comment: If it's available in the `ext` folder and also not commented in `php.ini` file then it should be installed, make sure you restarted the apache server, or maybe just restart the system.

Comment: As can be seen on these 2 links, the line is uncommented http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2g/aS/2UaVmzd1/snip.jpg
and the file is in my ext folder
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1r/AL/Xb3sF8V/snip2.jpg
I tried restarting the PC but it just won't work - same error message.
I don't know what else to do :/

Comment: Can you run `phpinfo();` and find out the path for `php.ini` file that is being used.

Comment: Run it in the console? (If so it just ignores the command)
the php.ini file I edited is the one I got when clicking on the wamp icon in the bottom right toolbar of windows and selecting PHP and php.ini

Comment: You may run the `phpinfo()` function from a `php` script, just create a `php` file, i.e. `htdocs/info.php` and write `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, then navigate this file using `localhost/info.php` from browser. each extension should have it's own section.

Comment: The phpinfo() statement shows that the ini file used is from: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini. I checked if the lines that should be uncommented in the file are uncommented and they are.

So the php_fileinfo.dll is uncommented in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

Comment: Thank you Alpha, it works on me, when I uncomment "extension=fileinfo" using Wnmp as local web server on a Laravel project.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 php.ini files:

> wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini
>   wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

Make sure the extension is uncommented in both, then restart apache.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. The trouble is that the php.ini file that Apache uses is different than the CLI one. Just search for php.ini in your wamp folder and change it in all of the files...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is because there are separate `php.ini` files for web/apache and CLI and as composer uses the CLI and phpinfo() uses the main `php.ini` the problem occurs.

If you run `php -m` in CLI and don't see the module's name you should find the CLI `php.ini` (in my case `php-cli.ini` and add the extension. e.g. `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

see: [Composer: The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332031/composer-the-requested-php-extension-ext-intl-is-missing-from-your-system)

Answer (score 0):

for me I just inserted in the list because i cannot find it
[ `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` ] after `[ExtensionList]`

```
[ExtensionList]

**extension=php_fileinfo.dll**<br>
extension=php_mysqli.dll<br>
extension=php_mbstring.dll<br>
extension=php_gd2.dll<br>
extension=php_gettext.dll<br>
extension=php_curl.dll<br>
extension=php_exif.dll<br>
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll<br>
extension=php_openssl.dll<br>
extension=php_soap.dll<br>
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll<br>
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll<br>
extension=php_imap.dll<br>
extension=php_tidy.dll<br>
```