# problem with extension impossible enable or install

Tags: php, http, module

php 7.3.5 hello i have a problem with the extension ext-http , and composer say me ext-http is missing even if i write this in composer .json , why ?
this this exact message:
 _Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-http * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's http extension. i tried to see th php.ini , and it i saw nothin to be relevant

with delete the entire vendor directroy it's work maybe it's cause to the version of php after ...

```php
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "psr/log": "^1.1",
    "ext-intl" : "*",
    "ext-http": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^5.0",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0",
    "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/debug": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
      "security-checker security:check": "script"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "4.2.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer update: The requested PHP extension ext-http missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675520/composer-update-the-requested-php-extension-ext-http-missing)

Answer (score 5):

Look at this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686959/11505413

Delete this line in your composer.json :

```
"require": {
"ext-http": "*"
}
```

Do a :

```
composer install
```

then :

```
composer update
```

Comment: Thanks ! If that helped you, you can upvote and mark this answer as the right one, even if it won't be displayed.

Comment: sorry i can't upvote my reputation is less 15 i have aldready demand to administrator to solve the problem , could you to help me for that ?please ?

Answer (score 1):

Just enable this in ***php.ini*** file by removing `;` if there is at the start of the line. That should be like this:
[image]

you can find it on XAMPP in this way:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

on the bash linux typing :`php -v`
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSE8n.png)

apres aller voir `/etc/php/<version>/mods-available`
in the file `ctype.ini` or other unrecognized extension: put the `extension=name.so`

[like :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZD8b.png)

Comment: It's okay to answer for linux users but it needs more explanations. What is the purpose of doing ```php -v``` ? (find your version of PHP I suppose)
Also on Linux the extensions prefixed with ```ext-*****``` are sometimes metapackages or modules to install on your system. So putting the name of an extension that is not installed on your system wont do anything. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679391/4726998