# Laravel 6.x. ext-http is missing in composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

When I'm Creating Panels using Laravel 6.x version. 
Maybe Fault in Laravel Version or Composer Version.
Also, I'm using **Jetbrains PHPSTORM** powerful PHP editor for Laravel.
[image: lara]

Comment: Check it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675520/composer-update-the-requested-php-extension-ext-http-missing

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing package / extension, all you have to do is to add it to your `composer.json` under `dependencies` - like so

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-http": "*",
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why you'd like to use `http\Env\Request` - are you sure you're not after `Illuminate\Http\Request` ?