# PHP: pthreads not loading on PHP 8.1

Tags: php, pthreads, php-8.1

I'm trying to add pthreads extension on PHP 8.1 TS and it doesn't seem to work, It's sayin that it is not installed while in fact it is.

```
PHP -v
PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2022 18:05:49) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

Here are the steps I used to install it ->

1. Get the latest release from here -> https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/
2. Extract php_pthreads.dll to /php/ext
3. Add extension=pthreads to php.ini
4. Extract pthreadVC2 in to /php

And when I try to install Laravel Horizon this is what I get ->

```
Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-pthreads * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's pthreads extension.
```

Comment: I've added it to the SYSTEM PATH + updated php.ini with 
extension_dir = "C:\xampp8\php\ext"

Still no result

Comment: The latest release name contains 7.0 and this package has been superseded. I also didn't find pthreads from [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/5.x/composer.json). Do you know who asks for this package?

Comment: It's the Laravel Horizon

Comment: Have you seen the link? Isn't it Laravel Horizon's composer.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**pthreads is not available for PHP 8.1**

PHP extensions need to be compiled against the correct version of PHP, because they interact directly with code that is only guaranteed stable within one annual release (e.g. 7.0.1 and 7.0.2 are guaranteed compatible, but 7.0.0 and 7.1.0 are not). They also generally require significant source code changes between major releases, i.e. an extension written for PHP 7.0 is reasonably likely to be compilable against PHP 7.4, but not against PHP 8.0.

If you look at [the downloads for an earlier version of pthreads](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/2.0.10/), you'll see that the version of PHP is included in the filename - pthreads 2.0.10 has builds available for 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6. The last release listed, [3.1.6](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.6/), only has two files available, both built for PHP 7.0.

Looking on Github, [version 3.1.6](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/releases/tag/v3.1.6) was tagged in Feb 2016, 10 months before PHP 7.1. There is a [version 3.2.0](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/releases/tag/v3.2.0) on Github, which mentions support for PHP 7.2, but this does not appear on [the PECL page for the extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads), which features a prominent banner:

> This package is not maintained anymore and has been superseded.

Specifically, it was [discontinued by the author](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/929) in favour of [a new extension called "parallel"](https://pecl.php.net/package/parallel). Unfortunately, that extension has not yet had a release which supports PHP 8.x either.

Comment: parallel supports PHP 8 now! https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel

Answer (score 0):

you can use `phpinfo();` method that will display all php extension you have install and make sure that you installed it in right php.ini file maybe that will fix your problem and you can also restart your localhost

Comment: I'm sure it's installed under the right php.ini, but for some reason it does not load up

Comment: "require": {
    "ext-http": "*"
} try to add this to your composer file

Comment: Composer returns another error with this line in plce ->
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-php * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's php extension.  Could it be that the 8.1 PHP is not supported by PHP pthreads ?

Comment: i don't think so , but maybe you need reinstall maybe something wrong happen during installation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675520/composer-update-the-requested-php-extension-ext-http-missing

Comment: check this problem above maybe you will find the solution